# Text processing - How to get multiple patterns in order from a file

Tags: text-processing

I have this `file.txt.Z` which contains this:

```
AK2*856*1036~AK3*TD1*4**~AK4*2**1*~AK4*7**1*~AK3*TD5*5**~AK4*3**6*2~AK3*REF*6**~AK4*2**1*~AK3*REF*7**~AK4*2**1*~AK3*REF*8**~AK4*2**1*~AK3*DTM*9**~AK4*2**4*20~AK4*2**4*20~AK3*CTT*12**7~AK5*R
AK2*856*1037~AK3*HL*92**~AK4*3**7*O~AK5*R~AK9*R*2*2*0~SE*25*0001~GE*1*211582~IEA*1*000211582
```

Each record consists of several fields starting with a header (usually `AK` with a number), separated by `~`. If you replace the `~` with an indented line break it would read:

```
AK2*856*1036
  AK3*TD1*4**
  AK4*2**1*
  AK4*7**1*
  AK3*TD5*5**
  AK4*3**6*2
  AK3*REF*6**
  AK4*2**1*
  AK3*REF*7**
  AK4*2**1*
  AK3*REF*8**
  AK4*2**1*
  AK3*DTM*9**
  AK4*2**4*20
  AK4*2**4*20
  AK3*CTT*12**7
  AK5*R
AK2*856*1037
  AK3*HL*92**
  AK4*3**7*O
  AK5*R
  AK9*R*2*2*0
  SE*25*0001
  GE*1*211582
  IEA*1*000211582
```

Each field has subfields separated by `*`. For example, subfield `AK201` is the first field after an `AK2` header, so it's `856` for the example lines.

As you can see there is 2 lines that has a starting string of `AK2`. That is like a line header or as we call it, Segment Header. There are two segment header in `file.txt.Z`. What I want is to get these data from each segment header in order:

**Data Needed:**

- AK202 (second field after `AK2` header) - `AK2*856*this_numeric_value` before the asterisk or `~`.
- AK301 (first field after `AK3` header) - `~AK3*this_string_value` before the `*` or `~`.
- AK502 (second field after `AK5` header) - `~AK5*some_string_value*this_numeric_value` before the `*` or `~`.
- AK401 (first field after `AK4` header) - `~AK4*this_numeric_value` before the `*` or `~`.
- Every numerical value from `AK4` or `AK5` field are should always be at least 2 digits. e.g. AK502 = 2; AK502 = 02 or AK401 = 9; AK401 = 09.
- If there is no `AK3` field, don't output anything. (I have already a script for this)
- If a line contains more than one AK3-AK5-AK4-sequences, they should get concatenated with a whitespace
- If the `AK5` field misses after the `AK3` field, look for `AK4` field instead.
- If neither an `AK4` nor an `AK5` field are present after the `AK3` field, Only output the AK301(first field after AK3 header).
- If there is more than one `AK4` field after an `AK3` field, concatenate the AK502-AK401-sequences by commas

**Output:**

```
GS: 1036 - TD102,07 TD503 REF02 DTM02,02 CTT
GS: 1037 - HL03
```

How to do this?
Just ask me if you're confused with my question.

**Edit:** This is my code: This is inside a while loop

```
while read FILE
do
    AK2=`zgrep -oP 'AK2.[\w\s\d]*.\K[\w\s\d]*' < $FILE`
    AK3=`zgrep -oP 'AK3.\K[\w\s\d]*' < $FILE`
    AK5=`zgrep -oP 'AK5.[\w\s\d]*.\K[\w\s\d]' < $FILE`
    AK5_ERROR=`if [[ $AK5 =~ ^[0-9]+$ ]]; then  printf "%02d" $AK5 2> /dev/null; else 2> /dev/null; fi`
    AK4=`zgrep -oP 'AK4.\K[\w\s\d]*' < $FILE`
    AK4_ERROR=`if [[ $AK4 =~ ^[0-9]+$ ]]; then  printf "%02d" $AK4 2> /dev/null; else 2> /dev/null; fi`

    if [[ $AK3 ]]
    then
        if $AK5 2> /dev/null
        then
            echo "GS: $AK2 - $AK3$AK4_ERROR"
        else
            echo "GS: $AK2 - $AK3$AK5_ERROR"
        fi
    else
        echo "Errors are not specified in the file."
    fi
done < file.txt.Z
```

The problem with my original code is that It doesn't concatenate `$AK3` and, `$AK5` or `$AK4`.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71277/discussion-on-question-by-washichawbachaw-text-processing-how-to-get-multiple).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following perl script produces your sample output exactly when given your sample input.

It may not work exactly as you want on your real data file, but it is not being presented as a complete working solution.  It is presented as a base to start working from - play with the script, mess around with it, break it, fix it, change it to do what you want.

It is undoubtedly far from optimal, but it would be difficult to improve it much without a far more detailed knowledge / better explanation of your input data and your required output.

It processes each input line (aka "record", or "segment" using your terminology) and builds up a string to be printed out after the record has been processed.  Each output line is built up according to your specifications in the **Data Needed** section of your question.

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;

while(<>) {
  next unless /AK3/;  # skip lines that don't contain AK3

  # process each "segment" aka "record".
  my @fields = split /~/;

  # get segment "header" and 2nd sub-field of that header.
  my @segment = split(/\*/,$fields[0]);
  my $segment_header = $segment[2];
  shift @fields;

  my $output = "GS: $segment_header -";

  my $groupoutput = ''; # output for a given AK3 "group"
  my $last_go = ''; # used to avoid duplicates like "REF02 REF02 REF02"

  foreach my $f (@fields) {
    my @subfields = split /\*/,$f;

    if ($f =~ m/^AK3/) {

        if (($groupoutput) && ($groupoutput ne $last_go)) {
          $output .= " $groupoutput";
          $last_go = $groupoutput;  # remember the most recent $groupoutput
        };

        $groupoutput = $subfields[1];

    } elsif ($f =~ m/^AK4/) {
        my $ak401 = $subfields[1];
        $groupoutput .= sprintf("%02i,",$ak401) if ($ak401 > 0);
    } elsif ($f =~ m/^AK5/) {
        my $ak502 = $subfields[2];
        $groupoutput .= sprintf("%02i",$ak502) if ($ak502 > 0);
    };
  };

  # append the group output generated since the last seen AK3 (if any)
  # i.e. don't forget to print the final group on the line.
  $output .= " $groupoutput" if (($groupoutput) && ($groupoutput ne $last_go));

  # clean up output string before printing.
  $output =~ s/, / /g;
  $output =~ s/\s*$|,$//;

  print $output, "\n";
}
```

I saved this script as `mysteryprocess.pl` because I couldn't think of a more appropriate name.  Then I ran it with your sample data (in a file called `input`):

example output:

```
$ ./mysteryprocess.pl input 
GS: 1036 - TD102,07 TD503 REF02 DTM02,02 CTT
GS: 1037 - HL03
```

---

That "REF02 REF03 REF02" thing bothered me, so here's another version.  This one uses an array and a hash (`@groups` and `%groups`) to build up the output line, and another hash (`%gseen`) to prevent dupes within a record by remembering values that we've already seen and included in the output.

The groups data is stored in `%groups`, but hashes are un-ordered in `perl`, so the `@groups` array is used to remember the order that we first saw a particular group.

BTW, `%groups` should probably be a hash-of-arrays aka HoA (i.e. a hash which contains an array in every element), which would avoid the need for cleaning up `$output` just before printing it (by using perl's `join()` function rather than simply appending a comma and the new value to the strings).  But I think this script is already complicated enough for a newcomer to perl to understand.

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;

while(<>) {
  next unless /AK3/;  # skip lines that don't contain AK3

  # process each "segment" aka "record".
  my @fields = split /~/;

  # get segment "header" from 1st field,  and then 2nd sub-field of that header.
  # NOTE: "shift" returns the first field of an array AND removes it from
  # the array.
  my @segment = split(/\*/, shift @fields);
  my $segment_header = $segment[2];

  my $output = "GS: $segment_header -";

  my @groups=(); # array to hold each group name (ak301) in the order that
                 # we see them
  my %groups=(); # hash to hold the ak401/ak502 values for each group
  my %gseen =(); # used to avoid dupes by holding specific values of ak301+ak401
                 # and ak301+ak502 that we've seen before.

  my $ak301='';

  foreach my $f (@fields) {
    my @subfields = split /\*/, $f;

    if ($f =~ m/^AK3/) {

        $ak301 = $subfields[1];
        if (!defined($groups{$ak301})) {
          push @groups, $ak301;
        };

    } elsif ($f =~ m/^AK4/) {

        my $ak401 = sprintf("%02i",$subfields[1]);
        $ak401 = '' if ($ak401 == 0);
        next if ($gseen{$ak301.'ak4'.$ak401});

        if (!defined($groups{$ak301})) {
          $groups{$ak301} = $ak401;
        } else {
          $groups{$ak301} .= ',' . $ak401;
        };
        $gseen{$ak301.'ak4'.$ak401}++;

    } elsif ($f =~ m/^AK5/) {

        my $ak502 = sprintf("%02i",$subfields[1]);
        $ak502 = '' if ($ak502 == 0);
        next if ($gseen{$ak301.'ak5'.$ak502});

        if (!defined($groups{$ak301})) {
          $groups{$ak301} = $ak502;
        } else {
          $groups{$ak301} .= ',' . $ak502;
        };
        $gseen{$ak301.'ak5'.$ak502}++;

    };
  };

  # construct the output string in the order we first saw each group
  foreach my $group (@groups) {
    $output .= " $group" . $groups{$group};
  };

  # clean up output string before printing.
  $output =~ s/, |  +/ /g;
  $output =~ s/\s*$|,$//;

  print $output, "\n";
}
```

With the following input

```
AK2*856*1036~AK3*TD1*4**~AK4*2**1*~AK4*7**1*~AK3*TD5*5**~AK4*3**6*2~AK3*REF*6**~AK4*2**1*~AK3*REF*7**~AK4*2**1*~AK3*REF*8**~AK4*2**1*~AK3*DTM*9**~AK4*2**4*20~AK4*2**4*20~AK3*CTT*12**7~AK5*R
AK2*856*1037~AK3*HL*92**~AK4*3**7*O~AK5*R~AK9*R*2*2*0~SE*25*0001~GE*1*211582~IEA*1*000211582
AK2*856*1099~AK3*TD1*4**~AK4*2**1*~AK4*7**1*~AK3*TD5*5**~AK4*3**6*2~AK3*REF*6**~AK4*2**1*~AK3*REF*7**~AK4*2**1*~AK3*REF*8**~AK4*3**1*~AK3*REF*8**~AK4*2**1*~AK3*DTM*9**~AK4*2**4*20~AK4*2**4*20~AK3*CTT*12**7~AK5*R
```

The output is now:

```
$ ./mysteryprocess.pl input 
GS: 1036 - TD102,07 TD503 REF02 DTM02 CTT
GS: 1037 - HL03
GS: 1099 - TD102,07 TD503 REF02,03 DTM02 CTT
```

Notes:

- `DTM02,02` also got collapsed into just `DTM02`.  The dupe elimination happens for everything now.
- The merging of groups (i.e. elements with the same AK301 "name") also occurs no matter where in a record an element appears.  The previous version only merged **adjacent** fields/subfields if they were the same.

I'm not sure if either of these changes are what you want.

---

ps: if you don't have `perl` installed, this code would translate fairly easily to `awk`.  It's a very simple (simplistic even), straight-forward algorithm.

Comment: I'm studying your answer. As I try to run you script, `$ mysteryprocess.ph input.txt` it returns this error `Scalar found where operator expected at ./mysteryprocess.pl line 49, near ") # clean up output string before printing. $output" (Missing operator before $output?) syntax error at ./mysteryprocess.pl line 49, near ") # clean up output string before printing. $output " Execution of ./mysteryprocess.pl aborted due to compilation errors.`. Does it supposed to have opening and closing bracket?

Comment: sorry, copy-paste error.  that line should start with a `#`.  and the preceeding line should end with a `;`.  will fix.

Comment: a useful tip - on systems with a good perl installation, you can run `perldoc -f functionname` to read the docs on a function.  e.g. `perldoc -f split`, `perldoc -f shift`.  otherwise, try `man perlfunc` and start searching.

Comment: Yeah I already fixed it. It really outputs the data I needed from the file. I will study it and more about perl scripting. Can I source this perl script from a Bourne shell script?

Comment: You can run it from a sh script.   but it's not sh code, it's perl, so can't be `source`d or `eval`-ed in sh.  in theory, you could embed it in a sh script with `perl -e '....script here...'` just like you can with `sed` or `grep` or `awk` but you'd have to be very careful about quoting issues - the script uses both single and double-quotes in lots of places.  a heredoc with a quoted word (to prevent expansion) would work - e.g. `perl <<'EOF'` rather than just `perl <<EOF`.

Comment: @WashichawbachaW If this solved your task I suggest to mark the question as answered by selecting cas' answer.

Answer (score 2):

another go, to show an awk version, as cas suggested. Can probably be done far more neatly, but was a learning experience anyway.

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

function get_slice(elem, fc,       tmpArr) {
        split(elem, tmpArr, "*")
        return tmpArr[fc]
    }

BEGIN { FS="~" }

/AK2/ { 
    res = get_slice($1, 3) " - "
    tmpStr = ""
    # only continue with this line if there are any AK3 fields.
    # otherwise may as well skip whole thing.
    if (match($0, /AK3/)) {
        loc=2
        for (loc=2; loc<=NF; loc++)
            if ($loc ~ /AK3/) break

        for ( ; loc<=NF; loc++) {
            if ($loc ~ /AK3/) {
                # check to see whether the previous loop generated a duplicate
                # tmpStr will be "" the first time
                if (index(res, tmpStr) == 0)
                    res = res " " tmpStr
                tmpStr = get_slice($loc, 2)
                # c is a count of how many fields have been added after AK3.
                # once positive, "," will be added.
                c = 0
                }
            # add the other fields
            else if ($loc ~ /AK4/) { 
                if ((s = get_slice($loc, 2)) != "")
                    tmpStr = tmpStr sprintf("%s%02d", c++ ? "," : "", s) 
            } else if ($loc ~ /AK5/) { 
                if ((s = get_slice($loc, 3)) != "")
                    tmpStr = tmpStr sprintf("%s%02d", c++ ? "," : "", s) 
            }
        }
        # this is repeated at the end, to make sure the final set is printed.
        if (index(res, tmpStr) == 0)
            res = res " " tmpStr
        print res
        }
    }
```

simply initially splitting fields on '~' and then looping through all the available fields per line. Only when a field is needed is it then split into subfields on '*' to get the asked for elements. 'get_slice' returns "" if nothing is found, so this has to be checked for.

I think I've understood the question..